# Wordpress plugin form removes all the word spaces

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I've created a form using the Wordpress plugin Boxit 2 and for some reason when I use the text field it removes all the spaces.

Here's the page http://stneotsfilmfestival.co.uk/submit-your-film

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your question. I went to the site to have a look and it seems to work fine on my end.

Also take note that there are better form plugins out there for you to use such as ninja forms and gravity forms. Try those out instead.

Comment: What happened when you added text to the larger text field, then deselected that field. Agreed, the Boxit 2 has been pulled from themeforest so there's no support provided.